# Looping through an element in BeautifulSoup, but outputting only childs of said element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My current problem is determining how to use BeautifulSoup and Selenium in order to Web Scrape an eSports website called Rocket League eSports.

I'm able to find the data and I use Selenium due to the scripts used on their webpage. I then use BeautifulSoup to grab the data. From here I'm able to export all the team names, but I keep getting 'None' in my list when I append it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import soupsieve
import time

#create a Google Chrome session
browser = 
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/jdr1018/chromedriver')

#maximizes Google Chrome window
browser.maximize_window()

#fetches the URL
browser.get('https://www.rocketleagueesports.com/stats/')

#pause to allow page to load
time.sleep(4)

#search the container and find all elements with h5 tag to print 
given elements
#container = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('h5')

#hand over Selenium page source to Beautiful BeautifulSoup
soup_source = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')

namelist = [] #empty list for Team names

winpercentlist = [] #empty list for Win Percentage

rocketleaguedict = {} #empty dict for namelist + winpercentlist

#using XPath to find h5 element with class name and assinging it to 
teamnames
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h5[@class="name"]/a')
teamnames = [element.text for element in elements]
#loop through team names to get each individual team name
for name in teamnames:
    #if statement to determine if name is already in the list
    if name in namelist:
        #append each team name through loop into empty list.
        pass
    else:
        namelist.append(name)
#return namelist to verify
return namelist
#for i in container:
   #print(i.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

#once program is done close Google Chrome
browser.close()}
```

My output looks similar to this:

```
['CHIEFS ESPORTS CLUB']
['CHIEFS ESPORTS CLUB', 'NRG ESPORTS']
['CHIEFS ESPORTS CLUB', 'NRG ESPORTS', 'ICON ESPORTS']
['CHIEFS ESPORTS CLUB', 'NRG ESPORTS', 'ICON ESPORTS', 'RENAULT SPORT 
TEAM VITALITY']
['CHIEFS ESPORTS CLUB', 'NRG ESPORTS', 'ICON ESPORTS', 'RENAULT SPORT 
TEAM VITALITY', 'ERODIUM']
['CHIEFS ESPORTS CLUB', 'NRG ESPORTS', 'ICON ESPORTS', 'RENAULT SPORT 
TEAM VITALITY', 'ERODIUM', 'LOWKEY ESPORTS'] ...
```

This isn't exactly it but the point is they're a bunch of these 'None's and I can't figure out exactly why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h5[@class="name"]/a')
teamnames = [element.text for element in elements]
```

Explanation why your approach didnt work:

Your solution has many `None` because the values under column 'G', 'G/GM' etc. also have the same html tagname and class.

[image]

As a result, `teamnames` is a list of elements which contains numbers and they do not have `<a href>...</a>` html content in them. Calling the method `name.find('a')` returns `None` when such an element is not there ([link to BeautifulSoup documentation on find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)), hence you get a series of 6 `None`.

Comment: This actually works very well when I use the xpath however in my print statements since it reiterates through the loop for each 'team name' it adds one it one at a time. To fix this I want to do a return so it only shows the full list at the end of the loop. Is there a way to make it so the return works, since the error I get now says syntax return is outside the function, but I can't see how that works. - - I updated the code above to show what I currently have now.

Comment: just un-indent the `print(namelist)` and it should print after all the team names have been added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and requests to get the team names. The regex could probably be made even more efficient (I would appreciate guidance on that)

```
import requests
import re

res = requests.get('https://www.rocketleagueesports.com/ajax/standings-script/?league=7-57d5ab4-qm0qcw&season=7-cab6afe099-06tjgk&region=0&stage=7-57d5ab4-g1dsq3')
r = re.compile(r'name: "((?:(?!").)*)')
teams = r.findall(res.text)
```

---

**Sample of output:**

[image]

---

**Regex:**

View regex and explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/ROOcy7/1)

It basically targets the strings in a script tag which are of format `name: "TeamName"`. The negative lookahead is to ensure I get each team name as a group by stopping at " after team name; as opposed to one long match ending at " after last team name.

[image]

**Additional references:**

1. https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html
2. https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html